# TCPDF rendering issue

Tags: php, tcpdf

I am having an issue with tcpdf and rendering divs. Below is a cut down version of my code:

```
<?php
require_once (APP . 'vendors/xtcpdf.php'); 
ob_clean();
$tcpdf = new XTCPDF(); 
$tcpdf->AddPage(); 

$html = '<div style="width: 333px;height: 750px;float: left;border: 1px solid black;">     
        Col One Test
</div>

<div style="width: 333px;height: 750px;float: left;border: 1px solid black;">      
        Col Two Test
</div>

<div style="width: 333px;height: 750px;float: left;border: 1px solid black;">       
        Col Three Test
</div>';

$tcpdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');
echo $tcpdf->Output('test.pdf', 'D'); 
?>
```

The XTCPDF is simply just an extension to overwrite the header and footer so is irrelevant here as it is not used for now. The issue arises when putting this data into the PDF. Below is how the code renders when displayed in a webpage:

[image]

However when rendered in a PDF this is what I get:

[image]

Cheers,
Chris.

Comment: Why are you using div's?  If you need 3 columns then you should create 3 regions in TCPDF.  I never understand why people want to use HTML to create a PDF.  Just create the PDF using the built in tools for regions and layout boxes.

Comment: The reason I want to use divs is the code I am wanting to create a PDF from is also displayed as a webpage on my site. Therefore I was hoping to reuse the html I have written for both instances. The main reason for this (and it wasn't just for convenience) was if something needed changing I would only have to do this in one place and deploy the one file. Also I see no reason not to use divs when the class itself highlights that the writeHTML function supports div tags. I just find it strange how it is rendered in the PDF completely different to how it is on screen.